# Renaming multiple dplyr summarise_each calls

Tags: r, aggregate, dplyr, rename

I am aggregating multiple variables in multiple ways and keep having to rename in a very clunky way.  It would be simpler if I could rename all but then my grouped column (in this case date) would get renamed every time as well and wouldnt merge at the end.

```
df <- group_by(df, date)

sums <- df%>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum), v1, v2, v3)
names(sums)[2:length(sums)] <- paste0(names(sums)[2:length(sums)], "_sum")

means <- df%>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean))
names(means)[2:length(means)] <- paste0(names(means)[2:length(means)], "_mean")

maxs <- df%>%
  summarise_each(funs(max), v45, v46, v47)
names(maxs)[2:length(maxs)] <- paste0(names(maxs)[2:length(maxs)], "_max")

text.stats <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'date', all=TRUE), list(sums, means,  maxs))
```

Any ideas on how to clean this up? Perhaps forcing the behavior of summarise_each() to append the variable name when more than one function is called?

Comment: You can append a name in `summarise_each` in the development version, *dplyr_0.4.3.9001*: `summarise_each(funs(mean = mean))`

Comment: That is wonderful, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current way to do this is to use the .names argument to control the output names

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), mean, .names = "mean_{.col}"))
```

See the across() [docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)